# Bundler.require doesn't require dependencies which are in the gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have an application using bundler which works fine at the moment but I have to run it out of the project's bin directory. Now I'm trying to convert it to a gem.

`bin/myexecutable` (no changes):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'mygem'
MyGem::MyExecutable.new.main(ARGV)
```

`lib/mygem.rb` (no changes):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

require 'mygem/version'
require 'mygem/my_executable'
```

`mygem.gemspec` (new):

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'mygem/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  # ... omitting boilerplate specs of gem ...

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split($/)
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
  spec.require_paths = ['lib']

  spec.add_development_dependency 'bundler', '~> 1.3'
  spec.add_development_dependency 'rake'

  spec.add_runtime_dependency 'bindata'
end
```

`Gemfile` (moved dependencies to mygem.gemspec):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemspec
```

When I install the gem and attempt to run the executable, I get:

```
.../resource_file.rb:2:in `<class:ResourceFile>': uninitialized constant ResourceFile::BinData (NameError)
```

Copying the dependencies back to `Gemfile` makes it work again, but now I have redundant declarations of the same dependencies in two locations.

Why doesn't it work when using the `gemspec` declaration?

Comment: when i see that correctly, you have just one runtime dependency. instead of using bundler, just put a `require 'bindata'` in there. the error that you are getting might also be coming from the ruby executable in `bin` as it does a `require` without changing the loadpath. so it could load old versions of your gem when they are on the loadpath!

Comment: I actually have more than one dependency, I just cut it down for the sake of reducing the lines of question. Either way, I don't want to have to specify the same gem twice. :/  Also it looks like the example on rubygems.org doesn't change $LOAD_PATH either: http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#adding-an-executable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `require 'bindata'` at the top of `lib/mygem.rb`.

In addition, I recommend removing these lines from `mygem.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
```

Bundler expects that gems require their own dependencies (so that they still work when you require them without Bundler, too). When you have `gemspec` in your `Gemfile`, `Bundler.require` directly requires your gem, but not any of its dependencies. Putting that into a gem will cause it to interact poorly with apps that already use Bundler, and creates a runtime dependency from your gem to Bundler (which is not declared in your gemspec).

This is intentional behavior. There is some discussion on these Bundler issues:

- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/608
- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1041
- https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2018

Comment: Can you say explicitly what the solution is to this problem?  In other words, what needs to change in the original question so that `bindata` gets installed during `bundle install`?

Comment: Ian: nothing needs to change to install it during `bundle install`. I was talking about requiring it at runtime. I'll clarify the answer.